# Preimage of distinguished open sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If we have a morphism between two affine Schemes $f: X \rightarrow Y$ with $X = $ Spec $A$, and $Y = $ Spec $B$, is it true that $f^{-1}(D(g)) = D(f'(g))$? (where $f'$ is the associated map on the structure sheaves) If so, is there a simple proof? Otherwise, is there any other way to characterize the preimages of distinguished open sets?

Comment: Yes.  This is true more or less by definition.

Comment: The idea of the proof is that D(g) is the locus where g, thought of as a function on Y, doesn't vanish. f'(g) is the function gf on X,
so its nonvanishing locus is exactly the preimage of D(g).


Comment: Though I agree that this isn't a very good question (the answer is, "just work through the definitions"), it doesn't feel close-worthy to me. It's something I can imagine a mathematician outside of algebraic geometry being confused about, and I don't get the feeling that the asker is trying to get somebody else to do his work for him. Though it's elementary (and a bit lazy), it feels like it's fundamentally okay. Then again, maybe I'm just in a good mood.

Comment: I deleted my statement asking for a vote for closure and have now voted to close.

Comment: I agree with Anton. But oh well, if the question is bothering you so much, just go ahead :)

Comment: This user has not been seen in 46 days.  I think it's safe to close it.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought that this was a recent post. I should have looked at the date :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You may want to look at Hartshorne's 'Algebraic Geometry' section II.2. For example Proposition II.2.3 discusses this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also be done using abstract nonsense.

Regard $\operatorname{Spec}$ as a functor $\mathbf{CRing}^{\operatorname{op}}\to\mathbf{Sch}$.

As a left adjoint, $\operatorname{Spec}$ converts pushouts in $\mathbf{CRing}$ to pullbacks.

The pushout of $A\leftarrow B\rightarrow B_g$ is $A\otimes_B B_g\simeq A_{\overline{g}}$ where $\overline{g}$ the image of $g$ in $A$.

The pullback of $\operatorname{Spec}A\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}B \leftarrow \operatorname{Spec}B_g$ is $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}B_g$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Spec}{A_\overline{g}}$ is isomorphic to $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}B_g$.

To show that the underlying sets are the same, the following will suffice :

- The maps $\operatorname{Spec}{A_\overline{g}}\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}B_g\to\operatorname{Spec}A$, are inclusions.
- $\operatorname{Spec}A_{\overline{g}}$ is contained in $f^{-1}\operatorname{Spec}B_g$.